# How to share variable values in Cypress

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, cypress

I am learning to use [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). At this time, I have several spec files, structured as follows:

```
/cypress
  /integration
    /child-a
      list.spec.js
      item.spec.js
    /child-b
      list.spec.js
      item.spec.js
    index.spec.js
```

When a test run begins, I want to set a value, once. That value is coming from a web api. For that reason, I do *not* want to set that value before every single test. I also don't want to set it for every file. Instead, I only want to set it once. I then want to use that value in all of the tests ran in all of the spec.js files.

Is there a way to do this in Cypress? Kind of like a `beforeAll` or `beforeSession`? Or is there some other recommended way? The closest I saw was the `[before][2]` hook. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cypress fixture** should work for you!

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax

```
// cypress/fixtures/user.json
{
  "username": "tj",
  "password": "password"
}
```

```
// cypress/integration/login_test.js

cy.fixture('users').as('usersJson')  // load data from users.json
```

Comment: How do we handle if the json file itself dynamic would * works?
cy.fixture('*') ?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar question, but I wanted that variable to be dynamic. For example, I wanted the test user I was creating to have a date in its email, like test+1575177520@example.com.

To do that and re-use it through all the tests I wanted to use the following code, but couldn't use a fixture since JSON isn't executable:

```
test+${new Date().getTime()}@example.com
```

I found the `cypress/support/index.html` useful *(but I think you can initialize the variables in the specs too)*. By adding the following line to the file I was able to reuse that dynamic variable everywhere in my tests and it was unique to each cypress run.

```
// support/index.js
//...

Cypress.config('email', `test+${new Date().getTime()}@example.com`)
```

And then in my tests

```
Cypress.config('email')
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Executing code once before all specs:**

You can use the `before` hook you've mentioned in `cypress/support/index.js`..Here's what comment in my local suppost/index.js file says (Cypress version 3.2)

```js
    // This example support/index.js is processed and
    // loaded automatically before your test files.
    //
    // This is a great place to put global configuration and
    // behavior that modifies Cypress.
    //
    // You can change the location of this file or turn off
    // automatically serving support files with the
    // 'supportFile' configuration option.
    // You can read more here:
    // https://on.cypress.io/configuration
```

**Tip**: I'm using the exact same hook to execute a script which resets my DB state before the tests. I wasn't able to succesfully run some JS statements here, so I've put them to separate Node script and execute it with `cy.exec()`. I guess you could stdout the webapi value you need from that script. cy.exec() has means to read the output of commands it runs:

```js
before(() => {
  cy.exec("node import-ui-test-data-to-firestore.js", {
    failOnNonZeroExit: false
  });
});
```

---

**Sharing variable among specs:**
I can't really offer an advice on sharing variable across all specs, but you might find this helpful - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context